# Mover div o clase dentro de otro div - prependTo pero me duplica el contenido movido

Tags: jquery

Estoy moviendo el contenido de un div o clase dentro de otro div o clase con prependTo, el tema que el elemento que se esta moviendo es un loop, y al moverlo duplica todo el loop como pudo hacer solo que mueva el elemento actual, se duplica .img-curso dos veces por que existen 2 imágenes. espero se entienda igual dejo capturas y códigos deseo mover .img-curso dentro de .card.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".columns-1 .img-curso").each(function(elemento) {
        jQuery(this).prependTo(jQuery(this).closest(".columns-1").find(".card"));
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Quieres decir, que las imágenes sigue en su sitio, y en el card-body?

Comment: con el código que puse, si se mueven donde necesito, las imágenes están en card-body, y las muevo a card, pero necesito mover solo una, como ves en la imagen se mueven 2 o las que sigas poniendo es una especie for o while que va recorriendo imágenes, puedes poner las que quieras, pero al mover solo nesecito mover solo una imagen.

Comment: el código de arriba proporcionado busca todos los elementos `.columns-1` que contengan `.img-curso`. si solo quieres el primero de todos, puedes terminar el bucle con un `return false`